# Reset DataTable in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to reset a value (namely `row_last_clicked` in a DataTable) belonging to an object in R Shiny when a particular event happens.

The (simplified) workflow is as follows (my original application includes a query to a database so I simplified it here):

1. User type a search term (e.g. 'versicolor') into a search field ('which_species').
2. Result is displayed in a DataTable (`query_result_table`).
3. User select a row in the displayed DataTable (`query_result_table`).
4. The selected row is simply displayed in a new DataTable (`selected_row_table`).
5. The user type a new query term (e.g. 'setosa'). We expect the second DataTable (`selected_row_table`) to be reset and display nothing (until Step 3 hapens).

The problem is that if the user types a new query term then the `row_last_clicked` value of the first DataTable (`query_result_table`) keeps its current value so second DataTable `selected_row_table` will display a row of the current query result based on the previous selection.

I tried to modify value of `input$query_result_table_row_last_clicked` from code but it is read only.

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("which_species", label = h5("Specify species"), 
                       choices = c("versicolor","setosa","virginica")))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           dataTableOutput(outputId = "query_result_table"))
  ),

  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           dataTableOutput(outputId = "selected_row_table"))
  )
  ))
```

server.R

```
  library(DT)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # This might be a time consuming database query so I use reactive expression 
  query_result <-  reactive({
    data <- iris[iris$Species==input$which_species,]
    # Below code is needed to ensure |row_last_clicked| returns the actually clicked row and not rowname of the data.frame
    q <- dim(data)
    if (q[1]==0) {return(data)}
    rownames(data) <- 1:q[1]
    data
    })

  output$query_result_table <- renderDataTable({
    query_result()
  },selection = 'single')


  output$selected_row_table <- renderDataTable({

    selected_row_in_query_result  <- input$query_result_table_row_last_clicked
    if (is.null(selected_row_in_query_result)) {return()}
    selected_row_in_query_result  <- as.integer(selected_row_in_query_result)
    message(selected_row_in_query_result)
    data_to_display <- query_result()
    data_to_display <- data_to_display[selected_row_in_query_result,]
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below does what you need. The basic idea is that the data displayed in the single row table( `data_to_display`) is controlled by two `eventReactive()` functions. One is activated when `input$which_species` changes and just sets the `data_to_display` to `NULL` so you don't see a table. The second is activated when `input$query_result_table_row_last_clicked` changes (i.e. you click a row), and that does display the table based on the selected row.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui<-fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("which_species", label = h5("Specify species"), 
                       choices = c("versicolor","setosa","virginica")))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "query_result_table"))
  ),

  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "selected_row_table"))
  )
)

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # This might be a time consuming database query so I use reactive expression 
  query_result <-  reactive({
    data <- iris[iris$Species==input$which_species,]
    # Below code is needed to ensure |row_last_clicked|
    # returns the actually clicked row and not rowname of the data.frame
    q <- dim(data)
    if (q[1]==0) {return(data)}
    rownames(data) <- 1:q[1]
    data
  })

  output$query_result_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    query_result()
  },selection = 'single')

  data_to_display<-eventReactive(input$query_result_table_rows_selected,ignoreNULL=TRUE,
                 query_result()[as.integer(input$query_result_table_row_last_clicked),]
   )

  output$selected_row_table<-DT::renderDataTable(data_to_display())

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**Edited out one line based on the commnents**

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the response! As for your suggestions: 1. I changed the textInput with a selectInput to facilitate tests. The app is using the iris dataset so one can easily test it. 2. I tried observeEvent, however, one cannot override content of input or output variables. When attempted, error is thrown. 3. Since my variable 'query_result' is reactive I think your last piece of code would make no change. 'query_result' would react to changes in queried data I believe. Szilard

Comment: @John_Paul Thanks, this is the expected behavior! However, I found a bug in Shiny: in case `selection = 'single', server=TRUE` options for `query_result_table` the click event is not always firing the update (e.g. `rows_selected` or `row_last_clicked`) event. This happens if the user selects the same row again, for instance row1->row2->row3->row1. The last selection (row1) does not fire the update event. Selecting again row1 will trigger the update. Switching to  `selection='multi'` OR `server=FALSE` would solve this issue. Anyway, this is not to do with my original question, just FYI.

Comment: @John_Paul Unfortunately the above solution is not fully working as expected. Command `data_to_display<-eventReactive(input$which_species, NULL)` is not executed. The reason is why expected behavior is found is because `query_result_table_rows_selected` is NULL whenever a new query is initiated (i.e. `which_species` changes value). Thereby, due to `ignoreNULL=TRUE` the table is not displayed.

Comment: @Szilard I am not sure I understand. Is the program behaving as expected? Or are you saying that the `data_to_display<-eventReactive(input$which_species, NULL)` is superfluous due to the `ignoreNULL` argument? You are correct about that, but I decided to keep it as then the answer might be more general for other users with similar issues, but that don't involve `NULL`.

Comment: @John_Paul What I meant is that R does not enter into code `data_to_display<-eventReactive(input$which_species, NULL)` regardless of the value of the `ignoreNULL` flag. If you comment out the next `eventReactive` line then `data_to_display<-eventReactive(input$which_species, NULL)` will be executed. This says to me that R is not entering the first definition of variable `data_to_display` because it is redefined in the next line. I'm new to both R and Shiny so this is just a ques. The bottom line is that code is working according to the _expected logic_ but not because of this particular line.